# ¿Por qué me arroja el error : solicitud incorrecta?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice

Buenas,
Estoy tratando de consumir unweb service desde c#, pero al momento de obtener la repuesta en:

```
WebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse()
```

me sale el siguiente error:

> "System.Net.WebException: 'Error en el servidor remoto: (400)
>   Solicitud incorrecta.'"

Tengo que pasar 3 datos de tipo string por el servicio.

Este es mi código

```
string soap2 = @"<? xml version = ""1.0"" encoding = ""utf-8"" ?>
            < soap : Envelope xmlns: xsi = ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
                xmlns: xsd = ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" 
                xmlns: soap = ""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" >            
               < soap:Body >            
                  < txtGNV xmlns = ""http://tempuri.org/"" >              
                     < estacion > 9097 </ estacion >               
                     < fecha > 20180129 </ fecha >              
                     < rutatxt > C:\Gasolutions\ </ rutatxt >             
                   </ txtGNV >              
                 </ soap:Body >
                </ soap:Envelope >";

                             HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/Service.asmx");
            req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/txtGNV\"");
            req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            req.Accept = "text/xml";
            req.Method = "POST";

            using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
                {
                    stmw.Write(soap2);
                }
            }

            using (WebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse())
            {
                string algo = "todo lo que debería hacer";
            }
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.
Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

**El error 400 indica que realizaste una petición incorrecta, regularmente esto sucede cuando no enviamos los parámetros correctos a la petición, o el método en este caso POST no es soportado.**

Noto que el archivo SOAP tiene espacios innecesarios y lo más importante es que el contenedor debe ser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
...
...
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Asegura que soporta el método POST, elimina espacios y agrega el cierre de `soap:Envelope` :**

```
String soap2 = @"<?xml version = ""1.0"" encoding = ""utf-8""?>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
            xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" 
            xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">            
           <soap:Body>            
              <txtGNV xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">              
                 <estacion>9097</estacion>               
                 <fecha>20180129</fecha>              
                 <rutatxt>C:\Gasolutions\</ rutatxt>             
               </txtGNV>              
             </soap:Body>
             </soap:Envelope>";
```

Revisa la documentación: [Personalizando mensajes SOAP.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkwy2d72(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.